# only one method this.init() works in class

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Stumped here. When I try calling this.makeBoard(); it gives my a type error. Any help would be appreciated. I did not include my other methods, they give the same errors however.

Error: TypeError: this.makeBoard is not a function
at HTMLInputElement

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.board = [];
    this.currPlayer = 1;
    this.button = document.querySelector("#submit");
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const htmlBoard = document.querySelector('#board');
      this.width = parseInt(document.querySelector('#width'));
      this.height = parseInt(document.querySelector('#height'));
      while (htmlBoard.firstChild) {
        htmlBoard.removeChild(htmlBoard.firstChild)
      }
      this.makeBoard();
    });
  }

  makeBoard() {
    for (let y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
      this.board.push(Array.from({ length: this.width }));
    }
  }
}

new Game();
```

Comment: Because you have no element with `id="submit"` in your document when this code runs

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question. _"it gives my a type error"_ is not enough to go on

Comment: I can include the HTML inside of the code snippet as well if you'd like. However, the submit button is included in the HTML already along with a form for user input. the whole init() function works, EXCEPT calling other methods

Comment: Ah, you're trying to access `this` inside the event handler. See the linked duplicate

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector()` returns an element object not a string. You can get the content of the element using `.innerText`

In your example change the `this.width` and `this.height` declarations to.

```
this.width = parseInt(document.querySelector('#width').innerText)
this.height = parseInt(document.querySelector('#height').innerText)
```